# How secure is the Shanghai Airport left luggage facility?

Tags: luggage, security, shanghai, pvg

I would like to leave a large suitcase at Shanghai's Pudong airport for about a week.

[Official Luggage Service Website of Pudong airport](http://en.shairport.com/2012-11/13/content_15920657.htm)

Can anyone comment on the service as to whether it was sufficiently secure?

Comment: I noticed some votes to close this question. Is there something off-topic? Please let me know so that I can at least try and amend.

Comment: I think that the only way you will get a representative answer is by polling, which is off-topic.

Comment: Maybe there are statistics that one could cite. That I would count as a representative answer.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException If there are such statistics, it would be a good answer. I would be downright shocked if there are any though. Chinese government services do not - to say the least - frequently publish their own records of them stealing from their customers. I would assume robberies are not common enough in airports to warrant a statistic.

Comment: I think we have questions of a similar nature regarding Johannesburg airport. Besides stats there could be review sites such as TripAdvisor giving generally bad ratings for instance.

Comment: What if someone said the place is infested with thugs and you still utilized its services and nothing went wrong ? Similarly, what if someone said that place is as strong as Fort Knox and you checked in your luggage but unfortunately your luggage was stolen, then what ? I think its just a chance you will have to take. IMO one shouldn't leave belongings you can't live without in any locker rooms.

Comment: I think it can be reworded to be less subjective - something like - what facilities exist for secure luggage storage?  An answer might specify a safe, or x-rays + guards, and then the OP can decide if he wants to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Just to report, I tried out the left luggage facility in Terminal 2, and it was great. They x-rayed my large bag, placed it in an individual locker and gave me the key. The cost was (relatively) cheap at RMB 20 a day. I believe it was totally secure.